# Regular Expression not working in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to check below line in regular expression?

[albums album_id='41']

All are static except my `album_id`. This may be `41` or else.

Below my code I have tried but that one not working:

```
$str = "[albums album_id='41']";
$regex = '/^[albums album_id=\'[0-9]\']$/';
if (preg_match($regex, $str)) {
    echo $str . " is a valid album ID.";
} else {
    echo $str . " is an invalid ablum ID. Please try again.";
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the first `[` and add `+` quantifier to `[0-9]`. The first `[` being unescaped created a character class - `[albums album_id=\'[0-9]` and that is something you did not expect.

Use

```
$regex = '/^\[albums album_id=\'[0-9]+\']$/';
```

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\[` - **a literal `[`**
- `albums album_id=\'`- a literal string `albums album_id='`
- `[0-9]+` - **one or more** digits (thanks to the `+` quantifier, if there can be no digits here, use `*` quantifier)
- `\']` - a literal string `']`
- `$` - end of string.

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/GmL7WL):

```
$str = "[albums album_id='41']";
$regex = '/^\[albums album_id=\'[0-9]+\']$/';
if (preg_match($regex, $str)) {
    echo $str . " is a valid album ID.";
} else {
    echo $str . " is an invalid ablum ID. Please try again.";
}
// => [albums album_id='41'] is a valid album ID.
```

Comment: FYI: Though I mentioned it in my answer, I will add here: if the ID can be empty, use `$regex = '/^\[albums album_id=\'[0-9]*\']$/';`. And this is not mentioned: if you need to *extract* the number, add parentheses around that pattern: `$regex = '/^\[albums album_id=\'([0-9]*)\']$/';` + use a third argument in `preg_match` - `preg_match($regex, $str, $matches)`, the value will be in `$matches[1]`. See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/mvUK4s).

Comment: Thank you for your nice answering.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your regex code, use this :

```
$regex = '/^[albums album_id=\'[0-9]+\']$/'
```

The + after [0-9] is to tell that you need to have one or more number between 0 and 9 (you can put * instead if you want zero or more)

To test your regex before using it in your code you can work with this website [regex101](https://regex101.com/)